90s film about a robot's slave boy who finds a mystical sword with old man's spirit and a man with spaceship
I'm looking for a cartoon that I saw In 90s. It was about a group of human slaves who work in underground. They are forced to work by robots. One of the young men finds a sword in the mine and a spirit of an old man came out from the sword and talked to the young man and then disappeared with the sword's blade. Only the handle of the sword remained. The young boy ran away with his girlfriend. His girlfriend is captured and killed by the robot's leader. The boy escaped into the jungle where he found a man with a space ship and after that with the help others they tried to stop the evil robots and free the people.

It sounds like Starchaser: The Legend of Orin (1985).
Young Orin lives in an oppressed, underground world in which humans have become the slaves of robots. One day the hero finds the handle of a sword and in a vision is told that if he can locate the blade, he will be able to overthrow the robots.
IMDB
Wikipedia

Trailer
